# LFTP: How to know time taken in transferring a file?

Tags: time, lftp

I am using LFTP for file transfer. The file transfer is successful but at the end of a successful file transfer, only the number of bytes transferred is displayed. I need to know the time taken in transferring the file, as well.

I am using LFTP because I need to provide the username, password and the required ftp command all in a single command. `(lftp -u username,password -e "your command;quit" ftp.site.com).` Therefore, using some other FTP daemon is probably not an option.

Is it possible to display transfer time using LFTP?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the time command.  Use it before most any command and it will give you a run down of the time it takes to complete that command.

```
time lftp -u username,password -e "your command;quit" ftp.site.com
```

Output will be like this:

```
real    0m2.963s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.012s
```